# SQL statement get the primary row

Tags: sql

In have a table with information about persons. Every person have more jobs.

Now I want a select statement, that show me all persons. And I get double rows. for example

```
Andı   coolies     study
Andı   coolies     b_study
Beli   flies       b_study
Cas    silik       study
```

I want in my select statement that give me only one row person and have a priority. 
I want only:

```
Andı   coolies   b_study
Beli   flies     b_study
Cas    silik     study
```

If `b_study` for a person is available than show the row.

Can some one give me a statement?

Comment: pls give table structures and example, it would be much easier to understand your problem

Comment: Provide your sql statement which you have tried.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please define 'have a priority' (prefix?)! Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Please share your best bet, the query you came up with.

Comment: Add (Cas, flies, study) to the sample data, and adjust the result.

Comment: Sorry for the low information I write from my smartphone and I don't have the data now!!!

Comment: But with the second two answers I can work!!! Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two selects with union:

```
select a,b,c from yourtable where c='b_study'
union
select a,b,c from yourtable 
where c<>'b_study'
  and a not in (select a from yourtable where c='b_study')
```